# C++ WinApi ListBox memory leak when get string from it

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-leaks, listbox

I have an owner-drawn ListBox that contains some strings. After this code executes:

```
char str[1000];  
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)  
    SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST, LB_GETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)str);
```

I have a memory leak about 2MB.
Why is it happen? How can I avoid this?
**UPD1:**
That code really haven't memory leaks. But in my program I have a global field

```
char listData[LAB_COUNT][LIST_STR_MAXCOUNT][STR_MAX_SIZE];
```

and in function:

```
int n = SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDL_LOG, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDL_LOG, LB_GETTEXT, j, (LPARAM)listData[i][j]);
```

and after this code appears memory leaks.

Comment: How do you find out that it has memory leak?

Comment: I set breakpoint on line before loop and after. Then I look at task manager

Comment: The code as posted does not leak memory. There is something in the listbox control or elsewhere that allocates the memory - which may or may not be released immediately. All task manager does it tell you how much memory the **program** is using not the state of the heap manager internal to the application.

Comment: Even with the update there is no memory leak. The 3-dimensional array is either an automatic variable, or an object with static storage duration. Neither one can possibly leak memory. If you think you found a memory leak, you have to provide information on why you think it is a leak. Task manager is not a tool to use. The [CRT Debugging Techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zh712wwf.aspx) are.